# How can I update my UI using DisplayPromptAsync in a command

Tags: c#, maui

I am quite new to mobile development in general and i have been trying to use mvvm on my expense tracker. Im trying to update my UI using the DisplayPromptAsync using a toolbar item.

This is my label to show by balance

```
<Label x:Name="balLabel"
       BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BalanceViewModel}}" 
       x:DataType="{x:Type vm:BalanceViewModel}"  
       Text="{Binding Balance.Amount}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

This is my ToolbarItem to add new expense

```
 <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
     <ToolbarItem BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BalanceViewModel}}"
                  x:DataType="{x:Type vm:BalanceViewModel}"
                  Text="Add Balance"
                  Command="{Binding AddBalanceCommand}"/>
 </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

This is my View Model for the balance

```
public partial class BalanceViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Balance balance;

    [RelayCommand]
        private async Task AddBalance()
    {
        string input = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Enter Balance", "Enter new balance", "OK");
        if(int.TryParse(input, out int result))
        {
            Balance.Amount += result;
        }

    }
}
```

My Balance Class

```
public partial class Balance : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int amount;
}
```

I tried creating a new ObservableCollection for the balance as i saw it work when listing my expenses which worked. Though it data does pass thru in the Command but it won't just update the UI. Can anyone help me and explain why won't it update my UI?

Comment: The properties of the Balance class need to be observable too

Comment: I just tried it and it still won't update

Comment: please [edit] the question and include the relevant code from the `Balance` class

Comment: should i just remove the class and move the property to the ViewModel?

Comment: No, I'd expect what you already have to work.  I would try removing the `BindingContext` from the `Label`.  You should only need to set that for the overall page, not each individual element.

Comment: i tried it and it's still doesn't work and the expense list just broke... i assigned it to each element because I already have my ExpenseViewModel set to the whole page to make my Listview work.

Comment: you generally shouldn't have two different VMs on a single page

Comment: oh... i thought that was possible. Ok i think ik what to do now thanks for clearing that up to me.

Comment: Must you use DisplayPrompt? I can implement a much cleaner Mvvm solution if it was an Entry instead?

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. I posted an answer and it worked well. I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are new to MAUI, I would like to point out that your problem becomes a whole lot easier if you had use `Entry` instead of `DisplayPrompt` because it allows for a much cleaner MVVM implementation:

```cs
// BalanceViewModel.cs 
public partial class BalanceViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _balanceAmount;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _newAmount;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void AddAmount()
    {
        if (int.TryParse(NewAmount, out int newAmount))
        {
            BalanceAmount += newAmount;
            NewAmount = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs - setup dependency injection

            // ...
            builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<BalanceViewModel>();
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs - use constructor injection
public MainPage(BalanceViewModel VM)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = VM;
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding BalanceAmount}"/>
    <Entry Text="{Binding NewAmount, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Text="Add Amount" Command="{Binding AddAmountCommand}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

In the above, we have a very clean separation between BalanceViewModel view model and MainPage view in that the view model is not supposed to directly call code belonging to the view. In your code, you are calling DisplayPromptyAsync from your view model, which, arguably, violates the separation of concern. This means your BalanceViewModel now has knowledge of MainPage and, therefore, cannot be unit-tested standalone.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code in viewmodel to this below, it works well.

```
public partial class BalanceViewModel : ObservableObject
    {

        [ObservableProperty]
        Balance balance = new Balance();

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task AddBalance()
        {
            string input = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayPromptAsync("Enter Balance", "Enter new balance", "OK");
            if (input!=null)
            {
                int.TryParse(input, out int result);
                Balance.Amount = result;
       
            }

        }
    }
```

In addition, you do not need to add `BindingContext="{Binding Source={vm:BalanceViewModel}}"` in every elements.

You can just add the code `BindingContext = new BalanceViewModel();` in the code behind like this:

```
public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new BalanceViewModel();
      }
```